# Spring - oauth2 - exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

I want to exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens with Spring oauth2 client package. My code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resource = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
  resource.setUserAuthorizationUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize");
  resource.setAccessTokenUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token");
  resource.setClientId("my-client-with-secret");
  resource.setClientSecret("secret");

  AccessTokenRequest request = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
  request.setAuthorizationCode("o9subu");

  AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider provider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
  OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = provider.obtainAccessToken(resource, request);

  System.out.println(accessToken.getValue());
}
```

The provider is from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/approval and I've taken the temp oauth2 code from the browser when I called the provider directly.

And the error message is

> Exception in thread "main" error="invalid_request", error_description="Possible CSRF detected - state parameter was required but no state could be found"
>       at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getParametersForTokenRequest(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:255)
>       at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:209)

I still want to request for access_token and secret_token by myself because I obtain the oauth2 code from another system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get the **refresh_token** you must have got  a **code** that will let you get it, to do that set **"&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force"** inside the url you send to get the **code**.
Then you can ask for **refresh_token** setting this parameters

```
code=your_code_generated
client_id=your_client_id
client_secret=your_client_secret
redirect_uri=https://oauth2.example.com/code
grant_type=authorization_code

POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

You can see more detail in Google Identity Platform https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Answer (score 0):

Simple add this line after the set Authorization Code:

```
request.setPreservedState(new Object());
```